# AndEngine + Box2D It is possible to change the userdata of something at run time?

Tags: box2d, physics

I was just wondering if it was possible to change the user data of something at run time? Basically, I have a physics box2D body that is a sensor, but I wasn't it disabled at certain times. I figured I would just change the user data, so the flag in begin contact wouldn't be hit, but it doesn't change. Is there another solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it isn't possible at run time. What I would probably do if it is really necessary to do so, is to wrap the data passed in to some kind of struct or a class and then you can change the flag within that.